# Choppy video playback with vimeo and youtube

Tags: video, ati, flash

I am using Maverick Meercat on an Acer Aspire 5100 with 2GB of RAM and an ATI Radeon Xpress 1100 graphics card.

I can't watch any video at all on this computer. I use both Firefox and Chrome and they both have the same problem. When I attempt to watch vimeo or youtube videos the playback is so choppy that it can't be watched. I have installed everything I can (I think so anyway, I am a beginner with all this linux).

Any idea's? When the computer was running XP it didn't have these issues...

Comment: What flash player did you install? It is best to go with Adobe's official, because alternatives can be choppy or break unexpectedly.

Comment: Try running this in `Terminal` (`Applications->Accessories->Terminal`): `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree` and restart Firefox.

Comment: Hi, I have the new version that is automatically installed in chrome.

Comment: Wow!! Evgeny!! Thanks :).. just did it and video from both vimeo and youtube plays properly!! So, looks like firefox will be the browser of choice as the problem exists in chrome still..

Comment: I will re-post my comment as an answer, please tick it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Try running this in `Terminal` (`Applications->Accessories->Terminal`): `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree` and restart Firefox.

To make it work in Chrome, `sudo cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins/` and restart Chrome.

Comment: You don't need the symlink thing for chrome anymore

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal, and execute the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Is that working?Now can you play videos?

Answer (score 0):

With the chrome browser I had out of sync and choppy vimeo playback, and no playback at all with youtube.  I found this advice somewhere - can't find where now - however....

I downloaded and installed this - `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` from the software centre and now all is working perfectly.  When install is selected, a window pops up which says that "free fmpeg codecs .. must be uninstalled first".  If you go for that it seems you have to uninstall chrome as well.  I left both installed and chose the "install anyway" option and bingo!

I'll try and find where I stumbled across this solution and thank the contributor.   It's been a godsend to a total clueless newbie to Ubuntu.